# How can this java code display an output in BlueJ?

Tags: java, user-interface, bluej

The code below is for a graphical user interface that has a loginframe that will enable the user to input their credentials. However, when I run the code it does not show an output. Can anyone help?

```
        public void addComponentsToContainer() {
            container.add(userLabel);
            container.add(passwordLabel);
            container.add(userTextField);
            container.add(passwordField);
            container.add(showPassword);
            container.add(loginButton);
            container.add(resetButton);
        }
        public void addActionEvent() {
            loginButton.addActionListener(this);
            resetButton.addActionListener(this);
            showPassword.addActionListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Coding Part of LOGIN button
            if (e.getSource() == loginButton) {
                String userText;
                String pwdText;
                userText = userTextField.getText();
                pwdText = passwordField.getText();
                if (userText.equalsIgnoreCase("admin") && pwdText.equalsIgnoreCase("12345")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Login Successful" );
                    Home obj= new Home();
                    obj.setVisible(true);
                   // setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null, "Invalid Username or Password");
                }
            }
            //Coding Part of RESET button
            if (e.getSource() == resetButton) {
                userTextField.setText("");
                passwordField.setText("");
            }
           //Coding Part of showPassword JCheckBox
            if (e.getSource() == showPassword) {
                if (showPassword.isSelected()) {
                    passwordField.setEchoChar((char) 0);
                } else {
                    passwordField.setEchoChar('*');
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not really showing enough information in this particular case which is why your are asked in comments to supply a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Never the less, I'm going to go with the fact that you are utilizing a **JPasswordField** component.

To start with, for security reasons the [JPasswordField#getText()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getText()) method has been **Deprecated** as of Java 2 platform v1.2 and replaced with the [JPasswordField#getPassword()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) method which returns a **char[]** Array of the password entered. Although you may still be able to compile with the `getText()` method for this component on the Java platform you're working with, you **may** be experiencing issues with it when actually running the code.

Try using the [JPasswordField#getPassword()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) method instead and see if that makes a difference:

```
String userText = userTextField.getText();
String pwdText  = String.valueOf(passwordField.getPassword());
if (userText.equalsIgnoreCase("admin") && pwdText.equalsIgnoreCase("12345")) {
```

and it should fly...maybe...who knows without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Are you using a `JPasswordField` or are you using a `JTextField` with a **DocumentFilter** to mask the entered text?

Maybe your code is working and you just can't see the Message Box because you use `null` as the parent for the **JOptionPane**:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Login Successful" );
```

and the message box dialog window is sitting *behind* your application window. This is rather typical if the application window has the `setAlwaysOnTop()` property set to boolean `true`. This *can* give the impression that the application is hanging. Give the dialog a parent...perhaps try `loginButton` instead of `null`.

**On a side note:**

Consider **hashing** passwords then compare a hash with a hash. You really shouldn't hard-code or store a password as *plain-text*.